# How to make triangular progress bar using highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have done the progress bar in circle ( [circular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypHzp.png) )but I want to do with triangle also. Is it possible to make in triangle?

```
My Code(for circle):
Highcharts.chart('myDivid'+i, {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: { 
            text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: 40,
                depth: 45,
                size:60,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                }
                }
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false 
            },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
        tooltip: { enabled: false },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                html: '<b>'+data.av+'%</b>',
                style: {
                    left: left,
                    top: '12px',
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Availability',
            states: { hover: { enabled: false } },
            data: [
                    {
                        y:data.availability,
                        color : data.availabilityColor
                    },
                    {
                        y:100-data.availability,
                        color : 'white'
                    }
                ]
        }]
    });
```

I have tried but i dint get how to do it for triangle.
I have made changes for this but not getting what I really want.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi @amit lodhi, Could you describe more precisely what you wan to achieve? Some simple visualization would be very helpful. Also, please check the `column-pyramid` series type: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-pyramid